# How to get the status.online flag on the client with mizzao:user-status

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have this publication:

```
  Meteor.publish 'online_users', ->
    Meteor.users.find({
      status:
        online: true
    }, {
      fields: {
        'status.online': 1
        _id: 1
        profile : 1
      }
    })
```

and subscription:

```
Meteor.subscribe "online_users"
```

In `meteor shell` on the server, I can do this:

```
Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {status: 1}}).fetch()
// [ { _id: '3afnN78MCkSs8w8W6',
//  status: { online: true, lastLogin: [Object], idle: false } } ]
```

however on the client I don't get the `status.online` data:

```
Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {status: 1}}).fetch()[0]
// Object {_id: "3afnN78MCkSs8w8W6"}
```

I am trying to make a list of users which is displayed on the client and which distinguished between those who are online and those who are not. I'm not sure how to do this without being able to see the `status.online` column on the client.

Comment: Your publication query is wrong. It won't match any user, as you should query the specific field (`"status.online":true`).

Comment: @MasterAM you're right. If I replace it with `Meteor.users.find({})` (no restrictions) it also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MasterAM pointed out in a comment, the problem was my publication.

`find( { status: { online: true } } )` won't work; it must be `find( { "status.online": true } )`